# reflect changes in one group to other groups at once

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have Photoshop CC and I have groups with different sizes (500x500, 1080x1080, etc).
I would like to have one group a.k.a. master group and when I change something in this group (backogroud, text, color of text, etc) these changes should be automatically immediatelly applied into all other "slave" groups linked with master group.

Is this possible please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently solved it by Smart Object layer.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only way it can be done in Photoshop.